# Unable to import prophet on yarn cluster

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, facebook-prophet

I am looking for a guide regarding
`python DataPrediction.py` running well. But when I submit

```bash
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 4g --num-executors 3 --executor-memory 3g --executor-cores 2 --queue default DataPrediction.py
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/vol1/hdata/nm-local-dir/usercache/ajit/appcache/application_1674580462889_0114/container_e14_1674580462889_0114_02_000001/DataPrediction.py", line 7, in <module>
    from prophet import Prophet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prophet'
```

Please help what should i do now.

Comment: Hi, have you found the answer to your question?

Comment: Yes, I found the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that prophet is not installed on the machines of your yarn cluster. There are multiple ways to package python modules and use them within a spark job (venv, conda, pex...). [Here is the official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html).

One solution is to use a venv.

```
python -m venv my_env
source my_env/bin/activate
pip install prophet venv-pack
venv-pack -o my_env.tar.gz

PYSPARK_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python spark-submit\
    --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --queue default\
    --archives my_env.tar.gz#environment DataPrediction.py
```